# Make Angular functions available to all controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I currently have some key functionality code in `app.run(function...` in Angular:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $window) {

  //window dimensions
  $window.width = angular.element($window).width();
  $window.height = angular.element($window).height();

  //initial variables
  var scrollTimer = false;

  //keydown event listeners
  document.onkeydown = function(e){

    //scroll down keys
    if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 40) {
      scroll(-1);
      e.preventDefault(); }

    //scroll up keys
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      scroll(1);
      e.preventDefault(); }
  }

  //scroll
  function scroll(delta){

    //check scroll timer
    if (scrollTimer) return;

    //new scroll pane
    if (delta < 0 && $rootScope.pane.count < $rootScope.pane.max) $rootScope.pane.count += 1;
    else if (delta > 0 && $rootScope.pane.count > 0) $rootScope.pane.count -= 1;
    else return;

    //apply current pane
    $rootScope.$apply();

    //animate scroll
    var scroll = $rootScope.pane.count * $window.height + "px";
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scroll}, 600, "swing");

    //reset scroll timer
    scrollTimer = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ scrollTimer = false; }, 1500);
  }

});
```

Now I have one controller (and possibly others) where I want to access the `scroll()` function. Like so:

```
app.controller("AsideCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope){ 

  //button scrolling
  $scope.scrollTo = function(index){
    index = index + 1;  
    scroll(index);    
  }

});
```

Of course this doesn't work because of `$scope`. Is there an easy way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular provider, you can find documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. So you can make provider which has your function scroll and that pass provider to your controller.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xvzm7b7/

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
myApp.service('$scrollService', function() {
    this.scroll = function(delta){
    //check scroll timer
    if (scrollTimer) return;

    //new scroll pane
    if (delta < 0 && $rootScope.pane.count < $rootScope.pane.max) $rootScope.pane.count += 1;
    else if (delta > 0 && $rootScope.pane.count > 0) $rootScope.pane.count -= 1;
    else return;

    //apply current pane
    $rootScope.$apply();

    //animate scroll
    var scroll = $rootScope.pane.count * $window.height + "px";
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scroll}, 600, "swing");

    //reset scroll timer
    scrollTimer = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ scrollTimer = false; }, 1500);
  }
    return this;
});
  //scroll

myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$scrollService', function($scope, $scrollService) {
    $scrollService.scroll();
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought a service might be the answer. I've read through that documentation before and find it a little complex and heavy. Particularly I struggle to call the service in my controller correctly. Could you provide a case example with my functions?

Comment: Didn't realise it was that simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the function in a service, and inject it it to the all controllers where you want to use it. Without messing with the rootscope

Simple example of service:
http://jsfiddle.net/clto/HB7LU/8220/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http){
  var myService = {};
  myService.doStuff = function(){
    return "Hello from service";
    };

  return myService;

}]);

//Inject myService in the controller
myApp.controller('MyCtrl1',['$scope','myService',
  function ($scope,myService) {
      $scope.msg = "Hello from MyCtrl1";

      $scope.foo = function(){
          $scope.msg = myService.doStuff();
      }
  }]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl2',['$scope','myService',
  function ($scope,myService) {
      $scope.msg = "Hello from MyCtrl2";

      $scope.foo = function(){
          $scope.msg = myService.doStuff();
      }
  }])
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">

    <button ng-click="foo()">Click</button>
        {{msg}}

</div>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">

    <button ng-click="foo()">Click</button>
        {{msg}}

</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand how to simply put the functions into a service and then call that service to trigger all the functions. The documentation hasn't really helped me with that. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$rootScope`:
just add after the function declaration `scroll(delta)`:
$rootScope.scroll = scroll;

and when you call it use `$rootScope.scroll` instead